# window.print() method stop the world

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use window.print() method, it will pause the javascript code(e.g. setInterval), when you close the print window, the code continues. See below for an example, I tested in IE9.0 and chrome 20.0

http://jsfiddle.net/f9aGR/

I also tried to open another page, then call window.print(), like

```
<a href='/1231' target='_newtab'>wtf</a>
```

However, calling window.print() will also pause the javascript in current page.

Is there a way to keep the coding running while the print window is opening? Both general and particular solutions will be ok.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using window.print() rather than setting the innerHtml of the body, or writing to the console with console.log()?

Comment: @DanPrince [`window.print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print) is for sending to the printer (the one that spits out real life paper) and has nothing to do with logging or changing the contents of the page :)

Comment: Ah...my bad, was thinking document.write for some reason. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, if the print was manually triggered by user, e.g. click the print button in the menu or press CTRL + P, it will not pause the javascript.

Now I have to ask our users to print the page by hand.